# Can't get Static Javascript file to Recognize Parse

Tags: javascript, express, ejs, parse-server

My HTML head is able to retrieve the file and communicate with the js file, but for some reason the js file stops working when I insert Parse. I'm using the MEAN stack with EJS and I set up the Parse server in my app.js. I also downloaded both the Parse-server and Parse.js using npm. That's working properly as well. What am I missing here?

This Works:

```
$(function() {

   alert('Test Alert');

});
```

This Doesn't:

```
$(function() {
    var parse = require("parse").Parse;

    var query = new Parse.Query('Chat');
    var subscription = query.subscribe();

    subscription.on('open', () => {
        alert("sub opened");
    });

    subscription.on('create', (object) => {
        alert('object created: ' + object.get('message'))
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have an error message? Are you using a bundler like browserify, webpack or rollup? What browser version? Are you using Babel?

Comment: I'm not using a bundler or Babel, and Firefox 51

Comment: oh snap, I'm gonna try out browserfiy

Comment: You need a bundler to use `require`. Budo is a fast way to get started with browserify.